# spark streaming functionality spark-submit time through exception

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, spark-streaming, apache-spark-sql, akka-stream

I am new to spark streaming.

when I am running spark streaming functionality as normal scala application,its working as expected.

I am able to capture my kafka event and able to store in hdfs itself.

when I am trying to run as my streaming  jar using spark-submit command,I am getting bellow error.

```
spark-submit --class Test  --master yarn  --executor-memory 20G --num-executors 50 spark-kafka-streaming-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar



16/02/16 08:39:23 INFO scheduler.JobGenerator: Started JobGenerator at 1455640800000 ms
```

16/02/16 08:39:23 INFO scheduler.JobScheduler: Started JobScheduler
   16/02/16 08:40:00 INFO utils.VerifiableProperties: Verifying properties

```
16/02/16 08:40:00 INFO utils.VerifiableProperties: Property group.id is overridden to
16/02/16 08:40:00 INFO utils.VerifiableProperties: Property zookeeper.connect is overridden to 
16/02/16 08:40:00 ERROR actor.ActorSystemImpl: Uncaught fatal error from thread [sparkDriver-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-2] shutting down ActorSystem [sparkDriver]
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka.DirectKafkaInputDStream.id()I
    ache.spark.streaming.kafka.DirectKafkaInputDStream.compute(DirectKafkaInputDStream.scala:165)at org.ap
at ache.spark.streaming.kafka.DirectKafkaInputDStream.compute(DirectKafkaInputDStream.scala:165)at org.ap   at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$getOrCompute$1$$anonfun$1.apply(DStream.scala:300)
at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$getOrCompute$1$$anonfun$1.apply(DStream.scala:300)
at scala.util.DynamicVariable.withValue(DynamicVariable.scala:57)
at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$getOrCompute$1.apply(DStream.scala:299)
at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$getOrCompute$1.apply(DStream.scala:287)
```

Please help me on this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

`InputDStream.id` is added to Spark Streaming Since 1.4. Therefore, it's likely `spark-kafka-streaming-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar` is generated using Spark 1.4+, while the Spark version of `spark-submit` is below 1.4.

Generally, you should always use the same version for compiling and runtime.

The first step is checking your spark-submit version using `bin/spark-submit --version`. Then check the version of Spark jars in your maven pom.xml (or sbt build file) and see if they are same. If not, update either one and just make sure they are same. To update `spark-submit`, you may need to download the proper version from http://spark.apache.org/downloads.html

Comment: Hi zsxwing,

Thanks for reply, same project when  I am trying to run as normal scala application it is working  as expected.

If it is jar related issue can please tell me how can I resolve this issue.
 
can you please suggest how can I make my spark-kafka-streaming-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar working as expected.

Can you please  elaborate  the answer.